# Program on c++ crash. Why?

Tags: c++

This code does not work. Please explain this. Just started to learn the language
Throws this message: "NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2019.2.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" : returned code "0xffffffff"
Stop."

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::allocator;

class FindAmountOutRange {
    int main() {
        findAmountOutRange(10, 2, 5);
        return 0;
    }

    static void findAmountOutRange(int amountNumbers, int firstIndexOfRange, int lastIndexOfRange) {
        int sum = 0;
        vector<int> numbers(amountNumbers);

        for (int number : numbers) {
            if (number < numbers.size()) {
                numbers.push_back(rand() % 100);
            }
        }

        for (int number : numbers) {
            cout << number << endl;
        }
        auto begin = numbers.cbegin();
        auto end = numbers.cend();
        numbers.erase(begin + firstIndexOfRange, end - lastIndexOfRange);
        for (int number : numbers) {
            cout << number << endl;
        }

        for (int number : numbers) {
            sum += numbers.at(number);
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does it output any other error messages?

Comment: Your main should not reside in a class. This is not java! Your program is missing its entry point.

Comment: @Aniosky you are new to stack overflow, please provide sufficient informations in your posts to ensure enough context to help you figure out stuff. Post the **whole** error message and post what you suspect is the case here. The whole error message would have told most of the people here what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is missing its entry point. The main function has to be present outside of a class like in C:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::allocator;

class FindAmountOutRange {
public:
    static void findAmountOutRange(int amountNumbers, int firstIndexOfRange, int lastIndexOfRange) {
        int sum = 0;
        vector<int> numbers(amountNumbers);

        for (int number : numbers) {
            if (number < numbers.size()) {
                numbers.push_back(rand() % 100);
            }
        }

        for (int number : numbers) {
            cout << number << endl;
        }
        auto begin = numbers.cbegin();
        auto end = numbers.cend();
        numbers.erase(begin + firstIndexOfRange, end - lastIndexOfRange);
        for (int number : numbers) {
            cout << number << endl;
        }

        for (int number : numbers) {
            sum += numbers.at(number);
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    FindAmountOutRange::findAmountOutRange(10, 2, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Please also note the `public:` keyword in a class which makes your function `findAmountOutRange` accessible from the outside (although you can argue about it residing in a class anyways as its just a static method).

In C++ you do not have to use classes. You can also just define functions like in C, so in your case, the function `findAmountOutRange` is unneccessarly put inside a class.